# Java - test for strings not working

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double start = System.nanoTime();

    String[] test = {"a","n","d"};


    System.out.println(test[0].equals("a"));
    System.out.println(test[1].equals("n"));
    System.out.println(test[2].equals("d"));

    System.out.println(AndTest(test));

    double duration = (System.nanoTime() - start) / 1000000000;
    System.out.println("Your code took " + duration + " seconds to execute.");
}


public static boolean AndTest(String[] n){
    int length = n.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length-3; i++){
        if (n[i].equals("a") && n[i+1].equals("n") && n[i+2].equals("d")) return true;
        if (n[i].equals("A") && n[i+1].equals("n") && n[i+2].equals("d")) return true;
        if (n[i].equals("A") && n[i+1].equals("n") && n[i+2].equals("d")) return true;
        else continue;
    }
    return false;
}

}
```

The output I get from this is:

```
true   //first character is a - tested in main body
true
true
false  // AndTest returns false
```

Why is this happening? Initially, I thought I'd made a mistake on my method for comparing two strings, but the test code I inserted above seems to be returning the correct output (true).

Comment: I think the `i<length-3` is causing the fault. Your array has size 3, so the comparison will be `i<0` and i is initially `0`

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 0; i < length-3
```

Your length should be 3 so 3 - 3 is 0. `0 < 0` all the time so it automatically returns false. Make it so its length minus 2. Or just i < 1.

Answer (score 1):

The following line causes your problems.

```
for (int i = 0; i < length - 3; i++) {
/* 
    length = 3, 
    length - 3 == 0, 
    0 < 0 == false, 
    the `for` statement doesn't execute
    the method returns `false` 
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why is this happening? Initially, I thought I'd made a mistake on my method for comparing two strings, but the test code I inserted above seems to be returning the correct output (true).

This happens because you are doing  `length-3` and this in your case is 0, so the `for` loop always will return `false` for your last line `return false;` so make sure that the lenght is minor.

I've changed your `for loop` to this :

```
public static boolean AndTest(String[] n){
    int length = n.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        if (n[i].equals("a") && n[i+1].equals("n") && n[i+2].equals("d")) return true;
        if (n[i].equals("A") && n[i+1].equals("n") && n[i+2].equals("d")) return true;
        if (n[i].equals("A") && n[i+1].equals("n") && n[i+2].equals("d")) return true;
        else continue;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And the output is

> true
>
> true
>
> true
>
> true
>
> Your code took 7.59064E-4 seconds to execute.

I don't know what exactly you want, maybe look for efficience but doing this takes less seconds to execute.

Comment: now (`i < length`), it looks like the exception will be thrown (`n[i+1]`, `n[i+2]`)

Comment: What exception are you talking about? I have no exceptions on my test, did you copy pasted the code?

Comment: it may be `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` theoretically